# INSERT INTO statement not working in NodeJS using mySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out the problem with the mySQL syntax I have.  I'm getting the error:

**{"message":"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?,?,?,?,(SELECT account_id FROM accounts WHERE account_name = ?),?,?,?,UUI' at line 1"}**

Here's the code on the backend I have set up:

```
const Customer = function(customer) {
  this.customer_id = customer.customer_id;
  this.contact_title = customer.contact_title;
  this.contact_first = customer.contact_first;
  this.contact_last = customer.contact_last;
  this.referral_source = customer.referral_source;
  this.initial_contact_date = customer.initial_contact_date;
  this.job_title = customer.job_title;
  this.account = customer.account;
  this.phone = customer.phone;
  this.email = customer.email;
  this.comments = customer.comments;
  this.created_by = customer.created_by;
  this.status = customer.status;
}

Customer.create = (newCustomer, result) => {
  console.log(newCustomer);
  const sql = 'INSERT INTO customers VALUES(UUID_TO_BIN(?, 1),?,?,?,?,?,?,(SELECT account_id FROM accounts WHERE account_name = ?),?,?,?,UUID_TO_BIN(?, 1),?);';
  db.query(sql, newCustomer, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      result(err, null);
      return;
    }

    result(null, { id: res.insertId, ...newCustomer });
  });
};
```

I can't for the life of me figure out where the error is, as it works on the workbench.  Any help would be *much* appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You forget to prepare the statement and to add parameters values.

Comment: You shouldn't have to prepare the statement if you're inserting into all the columns right?  And the values are coming from newCustomer.  The db.query values are sql = statement, newCustomer = values

Answer (score 0):

Actually found out the answer myself.  I was trying to use an object thinking that the values would be put into the statement.  Just had to make a new variable with the Object.values and put that into the database function.